# Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Transaction cannot proceed STATUS_COMMITTED

Tags: java, jboss, eclipselink, sqlexception

We have here a JBoss application with eclipselink. In very most cases all is ok and the application is running fine. But in some times we get a "Transaction cannot proceed STATUS_COMMITTED" and we don't know why. The interesting thing is that we get the exception while entering the EJB container ...

In which cases can be the error occurred?

Error in server.log:

```
15:17:18,450 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-168) [EL Info]: 2015-09-30 15:17:18.449--ServerSession(488658700)--Communication failure detected when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction. Attempting to retry query. Error was: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
15:17:18,453 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-168) Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Transaction cannot proceed STATUS_COMMITTED
15:17:18,454 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-168) Error Code: 0
15:17:18,454 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-168) Call: SELECT id, closed, changeSetID, xyFileVersionID FROM File.CHANGESETFILEVERSION WHERE (changeSetID = ?)
15:17:18,455 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-168)        bind => [1 parameter bound]
15:17:18,456 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-168) Query: ReadAllQuery(name="fileVersions" referenceClass=ChangeSetFileVersion sql="SELECT id, closed, changeSetID, xyFileVersionID FROM File.CHANGESETFILEVERSION WHERE (changeSetID = ?)").
```

Interesting part of the StackTrace:

```
15:17:28,550 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Thread-168) ARJUNA016029: SynchronizationImple.afterCompletion - failed for org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener@5c4b3928 with exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Transaction cannot proceed STATUS_COMMITTED
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT id, closed, changeSetID, xyFileVersionID FROM File.CHANGESETFILEVERSION WHERE (changeSetID = ?)
        bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="fileVersions" referenceClass=ChangeSetFileVersion sql="SELECT id, closed, changeSetID, xyFileVersionID FROM File.CHANGESETFILEVERSION WHERE (changeSetID = ?)")
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl$1.handleException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:696) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.handleException(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:275) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.afterCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:242) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.afterCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:79) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.afterCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:96)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.afterCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:402)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:103)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:164)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:117)
        at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:92) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:232) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at con.xy.view.fileExplorer.UploadFilesCtlrBean$$$view95.moveFiles(Unknown Source) [c-onxyModel.jar:2.3 Build 1290]
        at con.xy.vaadin.fileExplorer.UploadFilesView.updateModelValues(UploadFilesView.java:926) [c-onxyVaadin.jar:2.3 Build 1290]
        at con.xy.vaadin.util.XYViewComponent.doOk(XYViewComponent.java:411) [c-onXYVaadin.jar:2.3 Build 1290]
        at con.xy.vaadin.util.XYViewComponent.access$000(XYViewComponent.java:41) [c-onXYVaadin.jar:2.3 Build 1290]
        at con.xy.vaadin.util.XYViewComponent$DoOkWorker.workOutThread(XYViewComponent.java:668) [c-onXYVaadin.jar:2.3 Build 1290]
        at con.xy.vaadin.util.ThreadSwitcher.run(ThreadSwitcher.java:40) [c-onXYVaadin.jar:2.3 Build 1290]
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Transaction cannot proceed STATUS_COMMITTED
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT id, closed, changeSetID, xyFileVersionID FROM File.CHANGESETFILEVERSION WHERE (changeSetID = ?)
        bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="fileVersions" referenceClass=ChangeSetFileVersion sql="SELECT id, closed, changeSetID, xyFileVersionID FROM File.CHANGESETFILEVERSION WHERE (changeSetID = ?)")
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1611) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:674) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1991) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2738) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2691) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:495) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1168) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1127) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:403) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3203) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1793) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1863) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.retryQuery(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:999) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1829) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1863) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.retryQuery(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:999) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1829) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1863) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.retryQuery(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:999) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1829) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1863) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.retryQuery(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:999) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1829) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1775) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder.instantiate(QueryBasedValueHolder.java:129) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder.instantiate(QueryBasedValueHolder.java:116) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:89) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.buildDelegate(IndirectList.java:252) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.getDelegate(IndirectList.java:423) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.size(IndirectList.java:761) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.CollectionContainerPolicy.sizeFor(CollectionContainerPolicy.java:177) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.mergeIntoObject(CollectionMapping.java:1520) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4128) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeChangesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4061) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:884) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:698) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:309) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.mergeChangesIntoObject(CollectionMapping.java:1451) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeChangesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4070) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:884) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:698) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:309) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.mergeIntoObject(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:497) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4128) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeChangesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4061) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:839) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:698) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:309) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.mergeIntoObject(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:497) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4128) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeChangesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4061) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:839) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:698) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:309) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.mergeIntoObject(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:497) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4128) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeChangesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4061) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:839) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:698) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:309) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeChangesIntoParent(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3280) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.mergeChangesIntoParent(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:376) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeClonesAfterCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3412) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.afterCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:217) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        ... 35 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Transaction cannot proceed STATUS_COMMITTED
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.checkTransactionActive(WrapperDataSource.java:240)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransactionActive(WrappedConnection.java:1599)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkStatus(WrappedConnection.java:1614)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransaction(WrappedConnection.java:1588)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:397)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1556) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1505) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:778) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:619) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
        ... 104 more
```

**UPDATE**

Error occurres another time last week. After analysing log's it seems that the Exception is thorn while **leaving** the EJB container and not while entering it. Have post this also at the eclipselink forum:

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1071490/

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is a bug in eclipselink. I have post a bug to the eclipselink team:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=481185

Answer (score 0):

While only slightly related as this is also occurring with Hibernate 5 in JBoss EAP 7.0 with a JTA Data Source connecting to MS SQLServerExpress - Red Hat says this didnt occur in JBoss 4, only JBoss 6 and up.  You probably cant view the full solution unless you have a red hat support account but [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/793553) is the link. The problem and solutions labeled as "Transaction cannot proceed STATUS_COMMITTED" during commit in EAP 6 and later"

I do get the exception on every attempted commit with the commit failing.  Red hat basically says "Use an interposed synchronization registered when the connection is first obtained to clean up connection context as required"

They say the root cause is "Using a data source connection during the afterCompletion phase of the transaction lifecycle is not supported in EAP 6"

They also refer to this [discussion](http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/roadto12/txtracking.html) by Iron Jacamar regarding valid use of connections with regard to transaction boundaries.

They provide custom code supplied as an implementation of [org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider.html) and say see also the hibernate.connection.provider_class property defintion in [Table 3.4. Hibernate JDBC and Connection Properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional)

Hopefully this might help someone else regardless of if they're using EclipseLink or Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, use a new transaction for the method you are calling

```
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

worked for me.